# Tensorflow Object Detection API cropping segments of an image

Tags: python, tensorflow, crop, image-segmentation, object-detection-api

I am using Tensorflow Object Detection API with models that could detect objects with bounding boxes and masks.

Here is my code:

```
def run_inference_for_single_image_raw(image, graph):
  with graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
      all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
      tensor_dict = {}
      for key in [
          'num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores',
          'detection_classes', 'detection_masks'
      ]:
        tensor_name = key + ':0'
        if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
          tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(
              tensor_name)
      if 'detection_masks' in tensor_dict:
        detection_boxes = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_boxes'], [0])
        detection_masks = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_masks'], [0])
        real_num_detection = tf.cast(tensor_dict['num_detections'][0], tf.int32)
        detection_boxes = tf.slice(detection_boxes, [0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1])
        detection_masks = tf.slice(detection_masks, [0, 0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1, -1])
        detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(
            detection_masks, detection_boxes, image.shape[0], image.shape[1])
        detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(
            tf.greater(detection_masks_reframed, 0.5), tf.uint8)
        tensor_dict['detection_masks'] = tf.expand_dims(
            detection_masks_reframed, 0)
      image_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

      output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict,
                             feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})

  return output_dict
```

So if I run following code:

```
vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.grid(False)
plt.imshow(image)
```

The result is (Image with bounding boxes and masks):
[image: Image with bounding boxes and masks]

So, how can i crop image objects by mask path, **not bounding box**, so here in this example i want to have output images only with object (cat/bottle) on transparent background. (May be using PIL or OpenCV etc)

Comment: Can you paste the shape of 'output_dict.get('detection_masks')'? Or all the shapes if it does have sublists?

Comment: @NoumanRiazKhan with some image`output_dict.get('detection_masks').shape`, got this `(3, 1080, 1920)`, where 3 - amount of found objects, 1920 - image width in px, and 1080 - image height in px. So it brings numpy array of all found objects with dimension 1920x1080, with elements 0 and 1. Hence, this is binary mask of each object.
So, i want to know, how can i crop initial image by these binary masks.

Comment: Let me write the answer for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if`output_dict.get('detection_masks')` is numpy object and actually the binary mask, you can crop the image by simply multiplying or using `np.where`

```
mask = output_dict.get('detection_masks')
img_cropped = img * mask
```

This will crop all the detected objects but if you want to individually crop the objects, there is a way by detecting contours. We can use `scikit-image` for this

```
from skimage import measure
label_mask = measure.label(mask)
```

We have now labelled all the connected components in the binary image and assigned numeric labelled to each (by changing the pixel values). The labels start from '1' and ends at number of objects.

```
single_object_mask = (label_mask == 1) #or 2, 3...
```

This will filter the label_mask image with label you provided. You can also use the Bounding Box info to crop for particular object(s).